# Neovim: indent-blankline plugin, can't configure mixed indentation

Tags: lua, neovim, vim-plugin

I installed indent-blankline https://github.com/lukas-reineke/indent-blankline.nvim plugin with vim-plug. Their documentation probably has a mistake, because they show the same setup both for 'Simple' and 'Mixed' type of indentation. I can't configure it for mixed indentation (with horizontal dots and  scope highlight) in my indent-blankline.vim config file. For now only the vertical line shows up. Any idea?

```
lua << EOF
require('ibl').setup{}
EOF
```

Comment: *"Their documentation probably has a mistake"* - file a bug. Have it fixed, improve the situation for everybody.

Comment: @Friedrich any other solution you can suggest? I don't have time to fix their bugs. That's why I'm asking people here who have encountered this problem and can help solve it.

Comment: Raising an issue so the root cause can be fixed is actually the best suggestion I can come up with.